# how to customize scrollbar in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

My client wants to make two area in one page, and It should be scrolling individually. So i made it using two div with 'overflow-y:scroll' and customizing scrollbar. Running in Chrome, It was perfect. But running in IE, it has some problem. my problem is scrollbar's stylesheet is not working on top of the page.
I did research about 'customizing scrollbar', i can't find out the reason. Should i use 'iframe' without div tags?:(
That is the part of my stylesheet.

```
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    background:none;
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 3px;
    background:none;
}    
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #a9abad;
}  
.scroll{
    scrollbar-track-color: #fff;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-base-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-face-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #ffffff;
    scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Custom scrollbars are **not** supported in Firefox or IE/Edge.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

It's pretty much pointless to try.